# Dynamically rendering unknown quantity of different components in angular

Tags: angular

I have to build an app that dynamically renders a set of components using angular 4. The app should get a config from an API call and render the correct components according to config and pass data to each component.

The quantity, type and order of components to render is known only at run time.
I need to decide between:

1. `ngFor` that contains many `ngIf` for every type of "dynamic" component.
2. Using dynamic component loader to inject the components (is it possible if number of components is not known at build time?)

Which is the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)